# MySQLでデフォルト値付きの列の追加をしようとすると You have an error in your SQL syntax が出る

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQLで `ALTER TABLE T3 ADD id int 1;` とするとエラーが出てしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

**追記**

型 は 大文字表記 ですか？

Comment: いただいた情報だけですと推測で回答になり、的を得た回答がなかなか集まりづらいでしょう。まずは、利用しているデータベースサービスおよびエラーの内容およびエラーが再現するテーブル構成を追記いただくとより回答が得やすいでしょう。

Comment: 追加で質問ですが`int 1`の`1`とはどのような処理を期待してつけたのでしょうか？長さ？もしくはデフォルト値？

Comment: 初期値です デフォルト

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T3のテーブルにデフォルト値が1である int型のフィールドを追加したいということであれば
`DEFAULT`を利用してください。

```
ALTER TABLE T3 ADD id int DEFAULT 1;
```

MySQLでは大文字小文字の区別はないです。intもINTもどちらでも利用できます。
可読性の良さから、MySQLの予約語と自分の設定したフィールド名を区別するために大文字に書くことは多いと思います。

参考サイト
ALTER TABLE 構文
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/alter-table.html

Comment: ありがとうございます 確認できました

Comment: @hina 回答が来た場合はこちらを確認していただけるとよいと思います→[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: わかりました 理解しましたが ありがとうございます